# Wait for mutex or custom timeout/clock

Tags: c, linux, timeout, mutex, clock

We got a special situation in our embedded system.

We need to wait for OS-objects (semaphore, mq, mutex, sockets) and kick the waiters out after a user specified time.

All these objects have wait functions with timeout (e.g. `mq_timedreceive()`). However, we want to regulate the time, while users are waiting (to run faster in simulation mode). Therefore we cannot use the timeout functions but write our own timer that kicks them out.

This can be done via select/poll. Pseudocode example:

```
int tunblocker(int fd, int timeout)
{
   custom_sleep(timeout); // Time is controlled by us, not the OS.
   send(fd);
}

Content mq_wait(int fd, int timeout)
{
    int unblocker = open();
    spawn_thread(tunblocker, unblocker, timeout);
    int fdset[2] = {fd, unblocker};
    select(fdset, WAITFOREVER);
    
    close(unblocker);
    if(countActive(fdset) == 1 && isActive(fdset, unblocker))
       return TIMEOUT;
    else
       return read(fd, NOWAIT);
}
```

Problem: pthread_mutex is not a fd and cannot be used for select/poll. futex fd mode (`FUTEX_FD`) was removed. All other objects are fds (for semaphore: `eventfd`). Is there another way to do something similar without polling the mutex?

Comment: looking for something like this?  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html

Comment: As I said, `pthread_mutex_timedlock()` has a timeout parameter but I cannot control this clock source. (Well, its `CLOCK_REALTIME`, I could indeed control it, but only set it, not make it run faster. Also any other user (or NTP) could set it which is definitively unwanted.)